# How to Create a Frontend Html-list Editable in the Backend?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, images, list

I would like to add a feature to a page to display a short list of people, like the one [seen here](http://www.blenderbox.com/company/team).

I have done this on other sites by styling lists with css. This time however, it's for a client and I can't trust them to copy and paste a `<li>`, editing the name, job title and img name without messing it up.

What is the best way to go about creating this so that it can be easily reduced/added to in the dashboard? Basically, so that the user simply clicks "add person" then fills in some fields before updating the page.

Here is the architecture of what I've used in the past (to be styled with css)-

```
<ul class="people">
<li>
<img src="http://image_path.jpg" alt="a person" />
Jakie
<span> her job</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using a Custom Post Type and Custom Fields.

Although it can be created manually, a plugin can do it in a breeze.

Using [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/), I just did this in a couple of minutes:
[image: Custom Content Type Manager resulting interface]

Well, I did it fast because I'm used to the plugin. It has a bunch of options that can be overwhelming at first, but once they're understood it's all very easy. So, it's better to install it first in a testing environment before applying to the live site.

And it's [very well documented](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll give this a go. I'll be back (no doubt, to tell you I've messed up :p) to close question when I have it working. Thanks, again.

Comment: Hi, I took up your advice, installed this plugin and it works great thank you for the suggestion.

I have one tiny question, however.

In my index template file lets say I have something simple like:
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

I then browse to www.mysite.com/?post_type=staff and it will list titles of the posts I have added to the staff content type.

How/where can I add the '?post_type=staff' bit into my template file so that it shows 'staff' without having to use that url.

Thanks again, Ben

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't explain fully. This is my question, I posted the original question asking how to create the list. The above comment, though belated, is an extension of that question. I just thought, as you kindly offered the answer you could maybe help with the little issue I'm having. If not then I will post a new question. Ben

Comment: @Sue.My.Chin : Sorry, Ben, too many WPSE & SO tabs opened... Anyway, what you're asking **is a [New Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)**... I'll delete that "not a forum" comment right now, and this one afterwards. I suggest you do the same :)